# Firebase Cloud Messaging- Group of devices

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to create a group of devices in Firebase Cloud Messaging and I got an ioexception "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/googlenotification".
I have several questions about it:

1. What I need to put in fields: senderId, registrationId, idToken?
2. How I change this part of code to create a group and not add to group?
3. Where I need to put "authorization", "key=AIzaS..."?

Code:

```
public String addNotificationKey(
        String senderId, String userEmail, String registrationId, String idToken)
    throws IOException, JSONException {
    URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/googlenotification");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput(true);

    // HTTP request header
    con.setRequestProperty("project_id", senderId);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.connect();

    // HTTP request
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    data.put("operation", "add");
    data.put("notification_key_name", userEmail);
    data.put("registration_ids", new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(registrationId)));
    data.put("id_token", idToken);

    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    os.write(data.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
    os.close();

    // Read the response into a string
    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
    String responseString = new Scanner(is, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    is.close();

    // Parse the JSON string and return the notification key
    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseString);
    return response.getString("notification_key");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For #3:

```
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=AIzaS...");
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. What I need to put in fields: senderId, registrationId, idToken?

See their definitions in [Credentials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#credentials).

Sender ID can be found in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com). Go to Project Settings, then *Cloud Messaging* tab.

Registration token is generated on your client app side. See the corresponding setup documentation depending on the client app type [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

`idToken` is (AFAIK) only used on the client app side. See the (Android) documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#managing-device-groups-on-the-app-server).

> 2. How I change this part of code to create a group and not add to group?

Change

```
data.put("operation", "add");
```

to

```
data.put("operation", "create");
```

> 3. Where I need to put "authorization", "key=AIzaS..."?

See [Puf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197746/4625829).

Comment: what is the difference between id token to registration token?